# public DialogResult ShowDialog() help!

Tags: c#

I have two forms. 
The first form is the mainForm, this never goes anywhere.
On opening the second form (saveForm), it will display over the top.
When i close this form, I want a certain piece of code in the mainForm to run. 
I assume this is the correct way to get this to happen?

The code on saveForm when I close and return to the mainForm:

```
private void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Delivery d = new Delivery(txtNameBox.Text, txtAddressBox.Text, txtDayBox.Text, txtTimeBox.Text, txtMealBox.Text, txtInstructionsBox.Text, txtStatusBox.Text);
        mainForm.myDeliveries.Add(d);
        this.Close();
    }
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I will alter the question, was too vague.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the DialogResult property of you dialog form. Either explicitly in code or by assingning the dialog result to a button on your form.

```
private void btnSaveDetails_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Delivery d = new Delivery(
        txtNameBox.Text, txtAddressBox.Text, txtDayBox.Text,  
        txtTimeBox.Text, txtMealBox.Text, txtInstructionsBox.Text, 
        txtStatusBox.Text
    );
    mainForm.myDeliveries.Add(d);
    this.DialogResult = DialogResults.OK;
}
```

No need to call `Close()` setting this.DialogResult does that for you if you called the dialog using `ShowDialog()`.

On calling the form you have to do the following:

```
var frm = new MyForm();
if (frm.ShowDialog() == DialogResults.OK) {
     // do what you want to do on success.
}
```

Comment: I am closing a form with a button, and on closing that form and returning to the mainform, i want it to run a piece of code. I will alter my question with some code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the DialogResult returned to effect some change in your application. For example, if you provided the user with a dialog asking whether or not they want to delete all files and they respond by clicking the Yes button on your dialog, you would then delete the files.

More information about how to use DialogResult and ShowDialog vcan be found here: [DialogResult](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)

UPDATE: If the code you posted is from your "child" form, then what you've done so far is probably fine, BUT, you still need to provide a DialogResult **on that form** to communicate to mainForm that something was done. For example, you could do the following before this.Close():

```
this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
```

Then, in the code *after* the call to childForm.ShowDialog(), check the DialogResult. If it's equal to DialogResult.OK, then you can perform whatever task you need to that indicates the user clicked OK.

(And, on a side note, Dispose() is *not* called when you use ShowDialog(); you'll need to clean things up yourself, if necessary.)